# После добавления анимации игроку в Unity у него отключилась физика и управление

Tags: c#, unity3d, анимация, физика

Я делал анимацию игроку в Unity и у него отключилась физика и управление.
И ещё появилась ошибка: Asset 'player': Transition 'takeOf -> jump' in state 'takeOf' doesn't have an Exit Time or any condition, transition will be ignored
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

Вот код игрока:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public float jumpForce;
    private float moveInput;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    private bool facingRight = true;

    private bool isGrounded;
    public Transform feetPos;
    public float checkRadius;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;

    private Animator anim;
    private void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        moveInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);
        if(facingRight == false && moveInput > 0)
        {
            Flip();
        }
        else if (facingRight == true && moveInput < 0)
        {
            Flip();
        }
        if(moveInput == 0)
        {
            anim.SetBool("isRunning", false);
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("isRunning", true);
        }
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(feetPos.position, checkRadius, whatIsGround);

        if(isGrounded == true && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
            anim.SetTrigger("takeOf");
        }

        if(isGrounded == true)
        {
            anim.SetBool("isJumping", false);
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("isJumping", true);
        }
    }
    void Flip()
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
        Scaler.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = Scaler;

        if (moveInput < 0)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 180, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Вот скриншот аниматора:[image: скриншот с ошибкой и переходом]

Answer (score 0):

Нужно в инспекторе игрока в компоненте Аниматор поставить галочку на Apply root motion